# Racing two images on a Web Site using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, jscript

What I need to do is: 
Make two images race each other across the screen.
Have to randomly move the objects and make them move random lengths.
One one reaches a certain point I then display an image to show the winner.

I have it where they move and it generates the number and time. What ends up happening when I click the images to start the function, they just sorta jitter in place as if they don't understand their last position on the field. I am sure as heck this is something simple that I am missing, but would love some help. Yes, this is for a midterm project and I have been working on it, but I am not asking you to do my homework for me as that would be wrong. Here is what I have.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<style>

body{
    background-image:url('Images/duckstadium.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
}

</style>
<script>

var randleng;

function resetRace(){
window.location.reload();
}
//CHANGES ARE BELOW
//PLACED THE POS1 & POS2 OUTSIDE OF THE FUNCTION
    var pos1 = 0;
    var pos2 = 0;

function startRace() {

    var myVar1 = setInterval(startRace, 1000);
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    randleng = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

  if(ranNum == 0){

    var leng1 = pos1 + randleng;
    pos1+=randleng;
    document.getElementById("yellowHelmet").style.left = leng1 + "px";

    } 

    else if (ranNum == 1){

    var leng2 = pos2 + randleng;
    pos2+=randleng;
    document.getElementById("chromeHelmet").style.left = leng2 + "px";

  }
  //NOW THEY JUST NEED TO STOP FLYING OFF INTO TIME AND SPACE


if (pos1 == 1000)
  {
    alert("Yellow Helmet is the winner!");
    stopHelmets();
  }
  else if (pos2 == 1000)
  {
    alert("Chrome Helmet is the winner!");
    stopHelmets();
  }
  function stopHelmets(){
  clearInterval(myVar1);
  }
}

</script>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>The Great Oregon Duck Helmet Race!</title>
</head>

<body>
<img style="width:150px; height:inherit; position:absolute; top:400px;" src="Images/Oregon_Lightning_Mini_Helmet.png" id="yellowHelmet"/>
<img style="width:150px; height:inherit; position:absolute; top:600px;" src="Images/Oregon-Ducks-Helmet-psd88550.png" id="chromeHelmet"/>
<img style="width:200px; height:inherit; position:absolute; right:0px; cursor:pointer;" src="Images/oregon-logo.jpg" id="resetButton" onclick="resetRace()"/>
<img style="width:200px; height:inherit; cursor:pointer;" src="Images/oregon-ducks-logo_large.png" id="startButton" onclick="startRace()"/>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The alerts are just for testing purproses. They will do a getElementByID and display winning pictures of the helmet that wins.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make use of `pos1` and `pos2`. Currently, you're only changing the `left` property of each image by the amount of random movement per cycle. You need to either:

- add the random value to the present value of `left` or
- keep the total `left` value in the pos variables, and assign their values to the `left` property

One-image example of where your code is wrong:

- left is 0
- rand is 5
- left is now 5
- next rand is 10
- left is now 10 and this is the error as it should be 5+10

Here's a simple example demonstrating what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6ja5fx1f/

Comment: I understand where my issue is in my code, but the problem is trying to get it fixed and finding the solution. I basically would like to know how do I fix this with the pos1 and pos2 variables because I have tried various ways like adding the random length to the variables inside the if statements to keep track but then the images just end up doing the exact same.

Comment: `document.getElementById("yellowHelmet").style.left = randleng + "px";` this is the problem (for the other one also, of course). You are setting the left value to the current random factor, instead you need to get the current left value and add the random factor to it. (I'm still not giving you the solution because you said you want to learn from this)

Comment: Okay so now they just fly off into space and time

Comment: What makes you sure the pos will be exactly 1000 (your random goes up to 5, so it will skip number 1000 in 80% of the cases)? Isn't `>= 1000` a better check? Also, there's no need for those leng variables, because they have the same value as pos, just use pos to assign the left values.